# What is the use of both I²C and UART in Bluetooth module BM78SPPS5MC2?

Tags: i2c, stm32, uart, bluetooth

I am interfacing the Bluetooth module BM78SPPS5MC2 with the STM32F417IGH6 microcontroller as a host, but how do I use the two serial communication protocols to communicate?

Comment: How do you plan to interface between MCU and Bluetooth module.?

Comment: By reading the whole datasheet even if it is a hundred pages.

Comment: @laptop2d 100 page datasheet?  That sounds like some light night time reading.  Besides, the datasheet for the BM78SPP is only 60 pages.

Answer (score 2):

According to the data sheet, the UART is for host communications.

The I2C port is not for host communications and these interfaces are not alternatives to each other.

It appears, from other drawings, that the I2C port is for connecting a configuration EEPROM to the device. The data sheet doesn't go into the details of this.

Answer (score 0):

The vendor has given you two choices to interface their solution with your system.

It may seem useless but not all design requirements are similar. Some designs are short on some certain resources than others.

It may be unavailability of a particular interface or a particular interface is already heavily occupied in a system, so a design may prefer one interface over other. Instead of releasing two versions of a solution which differ only in interface they provide. They have released one version having some commonly used interfaces.

If you are concerned over that both interfaces will have different sets of commands or supported packet format , then I would like to mention that this generally not happen. There might be slight change in packet format mostly due to underline interface. You should have a look at the data sheet to get the better picture of it.

---

**Edit:**

However, the datasheet of `BM78SPPS5MC2` says the `I2C` has been used for configuration. `I2C` is directly connected to internal `EEPROM` of BM78SPPS5MC2. `UART` is used to communicate with Bluetooth stack of BM78SPPS5MC2. However, configuration is a one time task. You can configure it via I2C and disconnect the I2C lines from the BM78SPPS5MC2. You will need only UART interface afterwards.

Comment: This is wrong. You've guessed your answer and posted it, rather than checking the data sheet for actual facts. This IC has a UART for host communications and a separate I2C port for a configuration EEPROM. They are not alternatives for each other.

Comment: I tried to edit my answer just after posting the answer. But due to some network problem, my edited version wasn't submitted.

Comment: My Android app and the web page version keep crashing, sorry if my post was blunt, 20th attempt with crashes :-) Good stuff, glad you also saw what I meant.